# Does XCode 4 support Erlang syntax highlighting and code completion?

Tags: xcode, macos, ide, xcode4, erlang

Is there some plugin already? Or should I start writing one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ErlangXCode as a plugin will not work currently. I have not tried out XCode 4 yet so I don't know if the definition files have changed. If they are still the same you could be able to copy the `Erlang FileTypes.xcspec`, `Erlang Language.xclangspec` and `Erlang Syntax.xcsynspec` from the Github project page 'as is' to get at least basic syntax highlighting. In Xcode 3 you put these files in `~/Library/Application Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/` for example. But like I say either the spec files or the directory to put them in could have changed. But I doubt that the rest of the specification files, like for compilation, will work as is. But I guess you could try just moving all the specification files over. In worst case you might have to delete some of them again.

I will take a look at upgrading ErlangXCode to XCode 4 later. For now I have little time.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently there is this. I don't know anything about it, but it is possible that it only works with Xcode 3. Perhaps you could update it for Xcode 4?

https://github.com/JonGretar/erlangxcode

http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Developer-Tools/ErlangXCode.shtml